# I am unable to see he coverage statistics of my javascript module with sonarqube-gradle-plugin

Tags: ember.js, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, ember-cli-code-coverage

**Problem:**
I am unable to see he coverage statistics of my javascript module with sonarqube-gradle-plugin

Project Background
I have a multi module project being built with Gradle.
I am  using java as backend language and ember.js as  Frontend language.
I am trying to integrate Sonar for code coverage of both the codes.

I am using sonarqube gradle plugin 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.2' for sonar coverage.

Below is my sonar.properties

```
sonar.projectName=myproject
sonar.projectKey=com.ideas.myproject:myproject

sonar.modules=module-ui,module-services

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.projectBaseDir=myproject

module-ui.sonar.projectBaseDir=module-ui
module-ui.sonar.sources= module-ui
module-ui.sonar.language=js
module-ui.sonar.tests=tests
module-ui.sonar.javascript.coveragePlugin=lcov
module-ui.sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
module-ui.sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=build/coverage/lcov.info
module-ui.sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath=tests/reportfile.xml

module-services.sonar.projectBaseDir= module-services
module-services.sonar.sources=/src/main
module-services.sonar.language=java
module-services.sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
module-services.sonar.jacoco.reportPath=/build/jacoco/test.exec
```

**Details:**
I am using the ember-cli—code-coverage plugin which generates the lcov report .
I would want sonar to read the lcov report and show the coverage statistics on sonar.

The javascript plugin is installed on Sonar Server.

I tried to follow various answers to related questions on stack overflow but couldn’t find any success as yet.

**Issue:**
I can see the sonarcoverage of java module on CI but not for the JS module.
[image]

**One observation:**
I cannot see any LCOvSensor in the debug log. 
What am I Missing?
Please help.

**Log:**

```html
11:47:58.737 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Base dir: C:\jsproject\myproject\module-ui
11:47:58.737 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Working dir: C:\jsproject\myproject\build\sonar\com.ideas.jsproject_jsproject_module-ui
11:47:58.737 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: en_US
11:47:58.737 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Index files
11:47:58.738 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Declared extensions of language Groovy were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.grvy : **/*.groovy
11:47:58.738 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Declared extensions of language Java were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.java : **/*.java,**/*.jav
11:47:58.738 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js
11:47:58.738 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] 0 files indexed
11:47:58.752 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : C:\jsproject\myproject\module-ui\target\jacoco.exec
11:47:58.753 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: C:\jsproject\myproject\module-ui\target\jacoco-it.exec
11:47:58.766 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] 'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:47:58.766 [DEBUG] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensors : Lines Sensor (wrapped) -> SCM Sensor (wrapped) -> Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped) -> Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped) -> CPD Block Indexer (wrapped)
11:47:58.771 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensor Lines Sensor (wrapped)
11:47:58.771 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensor Lines Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
11:47:58.771 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped)
11:47:58.771 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensor SCM Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
11:47:58.771 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped)
11:47:58.771 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
11:47:58.772 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped)
11:47:58.772 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
11:47:58.772 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped)
11:47:58.772 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (wrapped) (done) | time=0ms
11:47:58.772 [INFO] [org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] -------------  Scan jsproject
```

Comment: Could you provide the logs of the analysis?

Comment: updated the post with logs .Hope this gives some more details.

Comment: The problem is that no JS file was found in module-ui. Why did you set "module-ui.sonar.sources= module-ui"? Is there a module-ui directory inside "C:\jsproject\myproject\module-ui"? Otherwise you should try "module-ui.sonar.sources= ."